# ejecutar script sobre una página que no sea de mi web

Tags: php, base-de-datos, web

Existe algún modo de ejecutar un script php (u otro lenguaje) sobre una página web que no sea mía? Por ejemplo accedo a una web de recetas donde los ingredientes sé que se estructuran de la siguiente manera :

```
<ul class="ingrList">
    <li class="ingr">Carne</li>
    <li class="ingr">Aceite</li>
    <li class="ingr">Sal</li>
    <li class="ingr">Oregano</li>
    <li class="ingr">Espaguetis</li>
    <li class="ingr">Tomate</li>
</ul>
```

Entonces, ejecutar un script que se encargue de buscar los elementos con la clase `ingr` y me los almacene en una base de datos o me los muestre en otra pantalla o similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saludos, eso se conoce como web scrapping. Existen librerías y herramientas para ello. Pero también hay que tener cuidado, que ejecutar tales acciones puede considerarse ofensivo para el propietario de la página web, e incluso conllevar acciones legales.